# Why does it show 0 when i use ${client.guilds.cache.size} in Discord.js?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

While making a Discord Bot, it shows 0 when client guilds cache size is used in the info command.   [in the chat it looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NbbMN.png)

```
const { DiscordAPIError, MessageEmbed } = require("discord.js");
const config = require("../config.json");
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();
const prefix = config.prefix;

module.exports = {
    name: 'info',
    description: "info",
    execute(message, args, Discord) {
        const newEmbed = new MessageEmbed()
        .setColor('RANDOM')
        .setFooter('Info for Laughing Horse ')
        .addFields(
            {name: 'Bot tag', value: '`Laughing Horse#6722`'},
            {name: 'Version', value: '`1.0.4`'},
            {name: 'Prefix', value: prefix},
            {name: 'Bot Dev', value: '`Skep#2721`'},
            {name: 'server count', value: `the bot is currently in ${client.guilds.cache.size} servers`}
        )
        message.channel.send(newEmbed);
    }
}
```

Comment: Assuming this isn't your index, there is no sense behind creating a new client for every single one of your commands. Not only that, but it actually hurts the code even more. I'd suggest replacing `const client = new Discord.Client();` with `const client = require(your index file);`

Comment: const index = require("../index.js");
const client = index.client                                                                                                {name: 'server count', value: `the bot is currently in ${client.guilds.cache.size} servers`} and i get an error         Cannot read property 'guilds' of undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said in the comment, `client.guilds.cache.size` is returning 0 because your creating a new client in this folder but this client never logs in to discord so hence 0 guilds loaded

`const client = require(your index file);` don't work as your not exporting client from index.js or anything like that,

As this is a command and you seem to be passing message from message event

`execute(message, args, Discord)`

You can do `message.client.guilds.cache.size`

Hopes this helps

ps: Your doing `Discord` in the execute function and also requiring it at the top, `const Discord = ...` you should remove one of these

Comment: lol np ; ) just remember to never create another client in different folder's because that client will never be logged on